# Exclude Document library items from search

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library that contains many files that I am linking to throughout the site, but I do not want them to be searchable using the site search.

Setting:

Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?

To "No" did not change a thing.

Is there anything else I should check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could go to SharePoint admin center-> more features-> Open Search->Remove Search Results. Paste the URLs into the "URLs to Remove" box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In this case I guess I will need to contact our admin, but is there really no way for site owner to do this ? Is Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Allow items from this document library to appear in search results for something else?